# Mysql: Update table with select max of another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different database in my MySql server.

```
First table DB1.contacts:

id | name | code
1  | foo  | 157
2  | foo  | 95
3  | foo  | 210

Second table DB2.paperworks:

id | name | contact_id
1  | foo  | 0
```

I would like to update DB2.paperworks, set DB2.paperworks.contact_id = max(DB1.contacts.code) of DB1.contacts.contacts table where DB2.paperworks.name = DB1.contacts.name

My desidered output should be:

Second table after query DB2.paperworks:

```
id | name | contact_id
1  | foo  | 210
```

This is my query:

```
UPDATE DB2.paperworks
JOIN DB1.contacts
ON DB2.paperworks.name = DB1.contacts.name
SET DB2.paperworks.contact_id = DB1.contacts.code
```

I don't understand how to write che "MAX(code)" condition. Can you help me, please?

Comment: not necessarily duplicate, since this could also be done with a simple update using correlated subquery, as shown in an answer below.

Comment: @SlimsGhost, well most questions have multiple possible answers. That doesn't mean they cannot have duplicates. I'm merely trying to direct OP to an answer of a question that seems relevant to his own.

Comment: @Chris, fair enough, just didn't want it to get closed with only a pointer to what might not be a desirable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly simpler form of `update` will do the trick:

```
UPDATE DB2.paperworks
SET DB2.paperworks.contact_id = (
    select max(DB1.contacts.code)
    from DB1.contacts
    where DB1.contacts.name = DB2.paperworks.name
    group by DB1.contacts.code
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE DB2.paperworks
SET DB2.paperworks.contact_id = (
    SELECT MAX(DB1.contacts.code)
    FROM DB1.contacts
    WHERE DB2.paperworks.name = DB1.contacts.name
)
```